# jQuery ajax call to a Java method

Tags: jquery

I am trying to call a java method inside of js using jQuery. The call is actually working as evidenced in Fiddler but the jQuery error method is always called and i can't get at the response. Not sure why this is happening. It's possible this is a cross-domain call but it is actually succeeding and i can get the xml response from Fiddler. I think I just have the wrong tags on the ajax method maybe. My 'data' is not an array or name/value pair as far as i can see, its just a string of xml that gets sent along. 
Did i miss something?

```
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: userManagementUrl,//the js call version of this
        data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><WebClientRequest xmlns="http://xsd.rt.state.id.us/usermanagerservice" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><requestMethodList><requestRights><userName>' + $("#loginUsername").val() + '</userName><password>' + $("#loginPassword").val() + '</password></requestRights></requestMethodList></WebClientRequest>',

        //async: false,
        //contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        //crossDomain: true,
        success: function (xml) {
            if (xml) {
                //parse through the xml response looking for status
                var node = $(xml).find("result").text();
                if (node) {
                    if (node === "success") {
                        boolLoggedIn = true;
                        $("#loginDialog").dialog("close");
                    }
                    else {
                        boolLoggedIn = false;
                        alert("login failed");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log("could not find result node");
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("error logging in");
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.warn("error in login call");
            $("#txtLoginStatus").html("<b>Login failed!</b>");
            boolLoggedIn = false;
        }
    });

    jqxhr.done(function (result) {
        console.log("Logged In");
        $("#loginDialog").dialog("close");
    });

    jqxhr.always(function (result) {
        console.log("Logged In");
        $("#loginDialog").dialog("close");
    });

    jqxhr.then(function (result) {
        console.log("Logged In");
        $("#loginDialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

Comment: When you say Fiddler, I'm assuming you're constructing a manual request, sending it, and getting a successful response? If I was debugging this I'd check that the request over the network was the same from both fiddler and from jQuery. Check the headers, etc. If it's just your parse that is failing, dump the result or check the response in Chrome's network panel.

Comment: the above code is tied to a button in my web page. When i click that button i see a request go out in Fiddler and i see the response come back as expected - its xml but Fiddler says that it is encoded so i click in Fiddler and it decodes it for me. But if that is all working then why would jquery go to the error method?

Comment: If you are really stumped on this I'd go grab the unminified source for jQuery and set some breakpoints. My guess is that jQuery doesn't like the way the response is formatted.